# Partially consuming a Publisher<DataBuffer>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive, spring-cloud-gateway

I am writing a `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter` (spring-cloud-gateway), that attempts to consume a response that follow a certain arbitrary protocol. The response body goes along the lines of:

```
200\n
header1:value1\n
header2:header2\n
\n
<the actual body>
```

The idea is, the entire response metadata from the downstream service is in the response body (much like how a SOAP envelope encloses the real body). The client of the gateway should receive a modified *unwrapped* response.

I've been following how `ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory` and `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory` as guide, but I don't think they fit my use case.

I believe I can achieve this by returning a subclass of `ServerHttpResponseDecorator`, but I can't wrap my head yet on how to go about implementing:

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
   // unwrap status code
   // unwrap headers
   // let it continue as usual 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
   return Mono.from(body).flatMap { buffer -> 
      val size = readUtf8Line(buffer)
      // recompute 'Content-Length', if applicable

      super.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer))
   }
}
```

The `readUtf8Line` is just my own method, that consumes the `DataBuffer` until it reaches a line break. It is also important to return the number of bytes read (i.e., `size`), because the `Content-Length` needs to be recomputed, if present.

Comment: Can u pls share the code to read the response from the buffer?